# Svn Client command Line Windows

Tags: windows, svn, cmd, collabnet

Is there any way to "browse" a repository through command line?

What I am doing is `svn list`:

```
svn list "http:svn-repository-url/Folder1/Folder2"
```

If I want to change folder from `Folder2` to `Folder1` I have to type the same command but one folder down, i. e.:

```
svn list "http:svn-repository-url/Folder1"
```

Is there any way to browse through remote repository without always type the `svn list` command?

Comment: How would you expect 'browsing' from command-line to work? I'm really curious. Are there any examples?

Comment: something resemble putty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what GUI clients such as TortoiseSVN are for. I'm personally not sure how you'd expect a *command-line* client to browse without having to `cd` into another path with `svn list`.

Comment: Something resemble Putty